# How to pass attributes(multiple attributes) to custom tags in struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, custom-tags

I am currently working on struts upgrade(migrating from struts 1.x to 2.x)

My project has a custom tag handler class for formatting numbers in the application

TLD file

```
<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>f</shortname>
    <uri>http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html</uri>   
   <tag>
        <name>formatNumber</name>
        <tagclass>com.taghandler.FormatNumberTag</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>property</name>
            <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>scope</name>
            <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>format</name>
            <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>       
    </tag>
   </taglib>
```

FormatNumberTag class

```
public class FormatNumberTag extends TagSupport
   {

    protected String name = null;

    protected String property = null;

    protected String scope = null;

    protected String format = null;

    //getters and setters of above member variables

    public int doStartTag() throws JspException
    {
        // Look up the requested bean (if necessary)
        Object bean = null;

        if (RequestUtils.lookup(pageContext, name, scope) == null)
        {
            return (SKIP_BODY); // Nothing to output
        }

        // Look up the requested property value
        Object value = RequestUtils.lookup(pageContext, name, property, scope);
        if (value == null)
        {
            return (SKIP_BODY); // Nothing to output
        }

        String output = null;

        if (format.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.PRICE_FORMAT))
        {
            output = CustomConverter.priceFormat(value); //custom class which formats number
        }
        else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase(MyConstants.PERCENTAGE_FORMAT))
        {
            output = CustomConverter.positionFormat(value); //custom class which formats number
        }


        ResponseUtils.write(pageContext, output);

        // Continue processing this page
        return (SKIP_BODY);

    }
  }
```

JSP

```
<f:formatNumber name="AccountBean" property="floatingRate" format="percentage" />
```

Here, AccountBean is the bean, floatingRate is the property & percentage is the format.

1) In tag handler class above,
    (**org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils**)RequestUtils.lookup &
    (**org.apache.struts.util.ResponseUtils**)ResponseUtils.write methods
    are used which are part of struts1 library.

- What are the corresponding methods & classes to be used in struts 2?

2) In JSP, 3 values/attributes(accountBean, floatingRate, percentage) are passed in the custom tag.

- How to pass attributes to custom tag in struts 2?
- How to pass bean, property & format to custom tag in struts 2?
          Please provide an example

Comment: Custom tags are custom tags; use the methods you'd use in any other non-Struts custom tag. That said, why are you doing this? Aren't there already custom tags that do formatting like this?

Comment: I am using custom tags with formatting logic in the custom tag handler class for formatting numbers. May I know which custom tag you are talking about that does formatting ?

Comment: I have made use of s:text tag for formatting numbers. It is working fine but I could not find message format for formatting negative numbers in parenthesis.Can you please provide message format for formatting negative numbers in parenthesis, that is Example: -0.52 should be displayed as (0.52)

Comment: IIRC Java number formatting supports a "negative number" format by separating the format strings with a semicolon, e.g., http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap24B%5Cch24B_15.html I'd start there and see if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found the solution. I used the message format - {0,number,##0.00'%';(##0.00)'%'} for formatting negative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Struts2 application, you can easily make use of the internationalization support in conjunction with the `s:text` tag in order to render formatted text.

By adding the following messages to the internationalization property files associated with the action or by defining a global message file via `struts.custom.i18n.resources`:

```
format.price={0,number,#,###,##0.00}
format.price.with.currency={0,number,#,###,##0.00} {1}
format.percentage={0,number,#,##0.00}%
```

Then in order to render them, your JSP code might resemble the following:

```
<!-- Render listItemPrice using the format.price layout -->
<s:text name="format.price"><s:param value="accountBean.listItemPrice"/>  

<!-- Render listItemPrice with currency code -->
<s:text name="format.price">
  <s:param value="accountBean.listItemPrice"/>
  <s:param value="accountBean.currencyCode"/>
</s:text>

<!-- Render percentage -->
<s:text name="format.percentage">
  <s:param value="accountBean.floatingRate"/>
</s:text>
```

**UPDATE**

If you need custom formatting, you can also leverage the `s:component` tag.

```
<s:component template="/components/numeric-format.ftl">
  <s:param name="type" value="%{'price'}" />
  <s:param name="value" value="%{accountBean.floatingRate}"/>
</s:component>
```

You can then define the `/components/numeric-format.ftl` freemarker template and add any specific logic you need

```
<span class="<#if parameters.value < 0>negative</#if><#else>positive</#else>">
  <@s.if test="${parameters.type?default('')} eq 'price'">
    <@s.text name="format.price">
      <@s.param value="${parameters.value}"/>
    </@s.text/>
  </@s.if>
  <#-- add other if blocks for various types and formats -->
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I added this pattern - ###,##0.#####;(###,##0.#####) in the properties file but it did not work as expected. 
format.price = {0, number, ###,##0.#####;(###,##0.#####)}. Is there anything wrong with the formatting pattern.

Comment: @Karthik The format must follow the convention of `MessageFormat`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html.

Comment: The custom tag handler class in my project contains code to format number as well as logic to display the number in red color if it is negative. Can this be achieved in struts2 using s:text tag?

Comment: @Karthik See my update.  I show how you can use the `s:component` tag associated with a freemarker template to create reusable UI components without having to rely on creating custom JSP tags.

Comment: I have made use of s:text tag for formatting numbers. It is working fine but I could not find message format for formatting negative numbers in parenthesis.

Comment: Can you please provide message format for formatting negative numbers in parenthesis, that is -0.52 should be displayed as (0.52)

Comment: For one you could use CSS ::before and ::after content styles for when the span class is `negative` to control adding the leading and trailing parenthesis.  Then just make sure you pass the absolute value to the text tag's parameter value.

Comment: I found the solution. I used the message format - {0,number,##0.00'%';(##0.00)'%'} for formatting negative values